# Improve performance for nested include in PHP using modals

Tags: php, html

I'm using modals in PHP so in the index.php I'm incluiding 8 .php files and all of them include the same .php so when the index is invoke it's calling the same .php 8 times.

For example

```
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'add_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'search_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'search_upd_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'search_list_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'action_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'upd_results_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'update_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
include $path_qa . $LTO_settlement_updates . 'list_results_LTO_settlement_updates.php';
```

And each of those include has inside the other include (the same one). So the index will go throug the same file 8 times.

How can I get a better performance?

Comment: Why not use `include_once` ? Also, how is this question related to HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_once` instead of `include`.